# How to use operators like *= and += with Dart maps and null-safety

Tags: flutter, dart, null-safety

If I have a map like:

`Map<String, int> myMap = Map();`

Add a key and value:

`myMap.putIfAbsent("yolo", 1000);`

Then add a number using an operator like `+=`

`myMap["yolo"] += 100;`

With null safety it throws an error saying

> The method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

In a map, what is the best way to set the value based on the key?

Comment: This is https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1113.  You currently will need to do `myMap['yolo'] = myMap['yolo']! + 100;`.

Answer (score 2):

This error is expected. If your map doesn't contain an entry with a key `"yolo"`, then calling `myMap["yolo"] += 100;` would cause a runtime null error.

If `0` is a sensible "default value" for this context, you could write something like:

```dart
myMap["yolo"] = (myMap["yolo"] ?? 0) + 100;
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter whether `map` contains the entry or not; `Map.operator[]` always returns a nullable type, which prevents using `+=` with it.

Comment: What you need is the `??+=` operator. :)